# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Here is the error:

```
gutschy@kiste:~/pizza/pizza_daten$ python datenimport3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datenimport3.py", line 20, in <module>
    ")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'            INTO TABLE pizzeria_table             FIE' at line 1")
gutschy@kiste:~/pizza/pizza_daten$
```

Here the datenimport3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'passw', 'pizzadb2');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(" 'Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'\
            INTO TABLE pizzeria_table \
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
            ENCLOSED BY '\"' \
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'  \
            IGNORE 1 LINES \
            (laden_name, vorwahl, telenr1, strasse, hausnr, \
            ort, linkname1, linkname2, linkname3, forum_link, \
            link2, link3, banner) \
            ")
```

Four month ago it works all fine, than I killed my debian 7 and now I'm on to bring it in the same way like before. I've add the last field "banner" new but I've done noting more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort through all that traceback chaff by looking for this:

```
...for the right syntax to use near ''Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'  INTO ...
```

On a 1064 error, MySQL presents, right after "use near", your statement starting with the place where its parse error was found.

Now, should not your statement start with

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE 'Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'  INTO ...
```

?

Comment: To cut to the chase, an efficient answer would be "Change your sql to start with  `cur.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE 'Adressliste_forum1_v4.csv'`".

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't understand why I delete this part of the code??